# Need clarification on the complex form of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I wish to ask you guys to fill in a few steps for the derivation of complex form of Fourier series.
This is taken from "Fourier series" of Tolstov (Dover publication).

$$f(x)\sim c_0+\sum_{n=1}^{m}(c_ne^{inx}+c_{-n}e^{-inx})=\sum_{\color{red}{n=-m}}^{m} c_ne^{inx}{\tag1}$$

The author said: "Therefore it is natural to write:

$$f(x)\sim\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{inx}\tag{2}$$

$c_n=\dfrac{a_0}{2}$, $c_n=\dfrac{a_n-ib_n}{2}$, $c_{-n}=\dfrac{a_n+ib_n}{2}$

I am totally confused with the summation index. Why does $n=-m$ lead to the exclusion of $c_{-n}e^{-inx}$. I have watched some youtube videos on the complex form of Fourier series but they don't write the standard Fourier series as a partial sum. I think the author skips some steps already.

Isn't $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-m}^{m}c_ne^{inx}$ means $f(x)\sim c_0+\displaystyle\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(c_ne^{inx}+c_{m}e^{imx})$

Also, how can you transform $(1)$ into $(2)$

Comment: Hi James, I've emailed you :)

Comment: Sorry, I have replied to you rather late. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
 c_0+\sum_{n=1}^{m}(c_ne^{inx}+c_{-n}e^{-inx}) &=& c_0+(c_1 e^{ix}+c_{-1} e^{-ix}) +\cdots + (c_me^{imx}+c_{-m}e^{-imx})
\end{eqnarray*}
Now rearrange the order of the terms to
\begin{eqnarray*}
 c_0+\sum_{n=1}^{m}(c_ne^{inx}+c_{-n}e^{-inx}) &=& c_{-m}e^{-imx} +\cdots +c_{-1} e^{-ix} +  c_0+c_1 e^{ix} +\cdots + c_me^{imx} \\ 
 &=& \sum_{\color{red}{n=-m}}^{m} c_ne^{inx}.
\end{eqnarray*}
How do we get from $(1)$ to $(2)$ ? ... What does the symbol $ \sim$ mean ?

Comment: I have fixed the typo for $(2)$, it is from minus infinity to positive infinity.

Comment: So you extend m to both infinities, right?

Comment: Are you happy that the terms in $(1)$ range over $-m,-m+1,\cdots,-1,0,1, \cdots, m$ ?